# Getting an XML result after POST HTTP Basic Auth in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, basic-authentication

This is driving me crazy so hoping for some help here.

I'm looking to get an authentication token after POSTing user information to an XML page using HTTP Basic Auth via PHP. The token is supposed to be returned back in XML. I'm using curl for this.

While I get absolutely no errors when I run the PHP, I am simply unable to get the token. I just get a blank page.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$username ='abc';
$password = 'xyz';

$user_token = base64_encode($username . '-' . $password);

$target_url = 'https://url_example/users/sign_in.xml';

$ch = curl_init($target_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$headers = array('Authorization=Basic ' . $user_token);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$response_data = curl_exec($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response_data);
print_r($xml);

if (curl_errno($ch)> 0){
die('There was a cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch));
} else {

curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be : not - 
try this

```
$process = curl_init("https://url_example/users/sign_in.xml");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $headers));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Getting a response now but still not getting the auth token. Trying to paste the response here but too long for the length of comment allowed.

Comment: can you paste in pastebin and paste so i can have a look